# WP: mysql query: add posts to a category that are in multiple categories

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, categories

I found a snippet for adding posts to a category that are in another single category:

```sql
# remember to replace @CategoryID and @OldCategoryID.   @OldCategoryID is in the middle
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order) 
  SELECT object_id, @CategoryID, 0 FROM wp_term_relationships tr2 
    WHERE tr2.term_taxonomy_id = @OldCategoryID AND object_id NOT IN 
      (SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships tr3
        WHERE tr3.term_taxonomy_id = @CategoryID);
```

however I cannot get it to work for posts in an array of categories.

so this does not work:

```sql
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order) 
  SELECT object_id, 101, 0 FROM wp_term_relationships tr2 
    WHERE tr2.term_taxonomy_id IN (61,62,63,64,65) AND object_id NOT IN 
      (SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships tr3
        WHERE tr3.term_taxonomy_id = 101);
```

help appreciated

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Why not use wordpress build in functions
[wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

example from wp:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['post_title'] ),
  'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
);
 
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: I am running a query on literally over 50,000 posts. It would be too slow to use wordpress codex